# Code coverage with Appium in React Native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, appium, code-coverage

I am using Appium and Jest for e2e test cases on React Native project. I would like to create a report of code coverage. I have gone through appium documentation as well, but didnt find any way to do it with Appium.

Is there any way to get it for React Native (Appium+Jest)?

Comment: did you get any solution here ? I am also looking for a solution to find code coverage of react native screens on app using appium automation framework.